# Wired behaviour of PHP SOAP Webservice on Ubuntu and apache2

Tags: php, apache, web-services, soap

We got a SOAP Webservice written in PHP. We also got PHPUnit Tests for this Webservice. Till last Week we used Xampp on Ubuntu 12.04.4. Using Xampp the Webservice worked fine. Last week we decided to use lamp instead.
We removed Xampp and installed lamp:
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-mysql mysql-server

Since then my SOAP Webservice behaves very strange! Every time i execute the same PHPUnit Tests I'm getting different results. But we got this Problem only on my computer.

We tried to execute the tests on another computer, calling my SOAP Webserviece - same result.

I removed and installed lamp a couple of times, without any success.

Does anyone have any idea, what the problem could be?

If you need any further information or config files etc. please tell me.

**Solved!**

Solution: in the Soap Webservice we were using PHP classes, PHP casted the webservice request (stdClass Object) to our custom classes. We never thought that might be a problem, course there where no errors thrown. But anyway, after we manually converted the stdClass objects in our custom objects, everything seems to work as expected.
We still have no clue why it worked on one machine, and not on the other.
Thanks for your Help!

Comment: is your soup extension enabled in LAMP?

Comment: Where can i check this? But I think it should be enabled, course I sometimes it works...

Comment: just go to your php.ini and find "soap", if at the beginning of it you see ";" character, then it is not enabled

Comment: also you can prior to that check it with `phpinfo()` function to see i it enabled.

Comment: both (SOAP- server and client) is enabled.